# Step-by-step tkinter GUI layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

How do I make a step-by-step GUI Layout with Tkinter Python 3.7? What I mean is that I want to have the user enter some information, press the "NEXT" button and enter some more information, etc. I don't think there's really a feasible way to completely change the layout like this with Tkinter, so I'm hoping there's something I'm missing. How do I do this?

Comment: Hi, could you please add some existing code that you've tried to use as it would help people give you an answer?

Comment: @coolio85 - I don't have any code. Is this still a valid question here? Sorry! I'm new to this.

Comment: Hi, try and take a look at the docs here https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html if you can't find your answer try asking the question with some included code that you've tried to use :D

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think there's really a feasible way to completely change the layout like this with Tkinter,

That is incorrect. This is trivially easy with Tkinter. Create a function or class for each step. All of the widgets for that step should be inside a single frame.

You then just need to call the first function or class to create the frame. When the user clicks "next", destroy the frame and create the next frame. And so on.

Comment: But I'm pretty sure this has a pretty noticeable delay. Like I would see one screen flashing away and then another screen flashing back up. Is this not the case? Could it maybe depend on the computer?

Comment: @JohnMariot: no, it will happen in the blink of an eye, assuming your own code isn't doing something inherently slow.